# Jquery show() dynamically built element

Tags: jquery

I have a empty hidden div that will include information from an AJAX call.  It works without the jquery show command, but I wanted to add the smooth opening of the div with jquery instead of the abrupt style="display: ''" approach.  The command to open the div is on line 7 of the function.  I took it out to get the jquery approach to work lower down in the function.

The code that I have that works is here:

```
function showImage(IDS, selectedID){
    var adType = new Array();
    adType = IDS.split("_");
    var thumbs = new Array();
    var adID = thumbs[0];
    var picImage = document.getElementById(adType[0] + '_' + thumbs[0]);
    //picImage.style.display = '';
    //picImage.className = "picDetail";
        removeChildren(picImage);
        var picThumbs = document.createElement('div');
        arLen = thumbs.length;
        //alert(arLen);
        if(arLen > 2){
        for ( var i=1, len=arLen; i<len; ++i ){
            //alert(thumbs[i]);
            var thumbNail = document.createElement('img');
        thumbNail.src = "../images/listings/" + adID + "_" + thumbs[i] + "_sm.jpg";
        thumbNail.className = "thumbNails";
        thumbNail.id = adID + '_' + thumbs[i];
        picThumbs.appendChild(thumbNail);
        picImage.appendChild(picThumbs);
        addHandler(adID, thumbs[i], 1);
        }
        }
        var previewImageContainer = document.createElement('div');
        var previewImage = document.createElement('img');
        previewImage.id = 'full_' + adID;
        previewImage.src = "../images/listings/" + adID + "_" + "1_.jpg";
        previewImage.className = 'thumbNails';
        previewImageContainer.style.width = "700px";
        previewImageContainer.style.textAlign = 'center';
        previewImageContainer.appendChild(previewImage);
        picImage.appendChild(previewImageContainer);
        var closeButton = document.createElement('img')
        closeButton.src = '../images/close_pix.png';
        closeButton.id = 'close_' + adType[0] + '_' + adID;
        picImage.appendChild(closeButton);
        addHandler(adID, 'close_' + adType[0], 2);
         //"butShowImage_" + thumbs[0]) is the name of the buttom that corresponds  //to the particular trigger and (adType[0] + '_' + thumbs[0]) is the name of the div I want //to open.  

 $("butShowImage_" + thumbs[0]).live('click', function () {
 $("#" + adType[0] + '_' + thumbs[0]).show('blind', {}, '200'); 
});
}
```

Am I using the wrong approach here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that use of `show()` is part of jQueryUI and not core jQuery (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Blind).  Make sure you're loading jQueryUI in addition to jQuery if this is the case.

Comment: @andrew: make your website already

Comment: I added the UI but still doesn't work.

Comment: This was something that I built about 2 years ago, then I started using Jquery recently and it does a lot of the stuff I want without me having to write a lot of new code.  Just trying to integrate what I already had.

Comment: please check using FireBug if `$("#" + adType[0] + '_' + thumbs[0])` is returning anything.

Comment: How would I check if it is returning anything....pardon if that is a stupid question.

Comment: I opened Firebug and when I click the button, that section of the page I want to show turns yellow in the firebug HTML tab

Comment: You create the `thumbs` array but you never add any elements, so im thinking `thumbs[0]` will be `undefined`...

Comment: @dragboatrandy 'How would I ...' when you fireup FireBug, go to console tab and paste `$("#" + adType[0] + '_' + thumbs[0])` into Textbox (one with > on left side, at bottom of pane) and press enter. see if it returns [0], null or undefined.

Comment: If I add an alert (thumbs[0]), it returns the ID that I am looking for, so that is not it.  In Firebug, when I click the button, it doesn't pitch an error and the div that I want to show turns yellow, so I am assuming it is triggering.

Comment: Ok I did check it in Firebug and it says adType is not defined, but if I put an alert("#" + adType[0] + '_' + thumbs[0]);, it alerts exactly what it is supposed to (the id of the div I want to open).

Comment: now one more thing try the string you get in `alert("#" + adType[0] + "_" + thumbs[0])` with firebug console like `var a="#" + adType[0] + "_" + thumbs[0]; alert($(a));` and see if you get something meaningful.

Comment: Still getting the ReferenceError: adType is not defined

Comment: the page is at http://www.randykrohn.com/classifieds/allAds.php?searchKey=AllAds

Comment: What should I do on page to run code? click on some link, button etc?

Comment: Under the picture of the boat at the top of the left column, there is a button that says "Show All Pictures", click that, and it should open a div below the buttons "Print Ad", Send Ad To A Friend", etc.

Comment: @dragboatrandy please see my answer. After making change, it shows two images small and a little bigger (thumbnails) and first one in full size below them :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change line

`$("butShowImage_" + thumbs[0]).live('click', function () {` (probably numbered 416) to

`$("#butShowImage_" + thumbs[0]).live('click', function () {`

Comment: That seems to have allowed it to open properly, but it appears I have to click the button twice.  Is there some reason for that?

Comment: If you click the button the first time after a page refresh, it doesn't open, but if you click it again, it will open.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to remove the trigger, because the function is already triggered by the button click.  So it works great now!  Can't believe the only problem was the "#" symbol.  Thanks for you help!